# Getting binary file out of the iPhone

Tags: ios, export, binaryfiles, binary-data

My iPhone app is creating a binary file (up to 20MB).  I would like to save this binary file and export it to my Mac.  This is strictly for development NOT for submitting to the App Store.  Any suggestions/recommendations on best practice for this?  I was thinking of an attachment to an email but want to ask some of you experts out there if there's a better way.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing this just for the development try to add `Application supports iTunes file sharing` (UIFileSharingEnabled) to your app's Info.plist file with YES value to enable sharing via iTunes.

Comment: thank you.  I was able to get data out of the iphone with your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Open XCode -> Organizer -> Applications -> Your APP -> Choose it and press download
All app data will be downloaded to archive, there is your file